# One dimension Matrix Sum

Tags: c++, vector, matrix

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int i;
    double scores[5]= {0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5};

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout<<scores[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering how could I make a line that shows the sum of the elements in scores[5] without using the `scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2]+scores[3]+scores[4];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the sum along the way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int i;
    double scores[5]= {0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5};
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout << scores[i] << " ";
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    cout << sum << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [*`std::accumulate`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
double sum = std::accumulate( std::begin(scores), std::end(scores), 0.0);
```

<sup>*`std::begin()` , `std::end()` requires `C++11`*</sup>

Comment: Re `std::begin()` and `std::end()`: any experienced C++ programmer had them in his tool kit (albeit not in `std::`) before there was C++11.  Although in this case: any experienced C++ programmer would probably be using `std::vector` anyway, and so wouldn't need them.

Comment: And finally, it's probably worth noting that `std::accumulate`
is _not_ a good way of calculating the sum of large arrays.  If
he's outputting the value for each element, and allocating the
array on the stack, it's certainly adequate, but it uses a very
naïve algorithm which quickly looses precision for larger
arrays.